# Inverse of this regex expression

Tags: regex-negation

I have a list:

```
50 - David Herd (1961-1968)
49 - Teddy Sheringham (1997-2001)
48 - George Wall (1906-1915)
47 - Stan Pearson (1935-1954)
46 - Harry Gregg (1957-1966)
45 - Paddy Crerand (1963-1971)
44 - Jaap Stam (1998-2001)
43 - Paul Ince (1989-1995)
42 - Dwight Yorke (1998-2002)
```

I want to select all characters EXCEPT the first and last name with the space in between in order to delete them and leave just the first name, space and last name.

So far I can select the first name, space and last name with:

```
([[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+)
```

But I am unsure of how to 'invert' this expression. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to match the surrounded data, and capture the firstname space lastname.

In the replacement use the capture group.

```
^.*?\b([a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+)\b.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VaWtBM/1)

Answer (score 2):

If regex replacement be an option for you, you could try the following in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    \d+ - (\w+(?: \w+)+) \(\d{4}-\d{4}\)
Replace: $1
```

### Demo

Comment: I don't think that's the link you meant to attach, just saying JSON that says `"Your regex has been deleted."`

Comment: @JoeLissner I'm on a mobile phone right now, and the link sometimes doesn't seem to copy over correctly.  I've fixed it (I think).